# Mysql query to find customers who have 0 orders between two dates

Tags: mysql

See SqlFiddle: [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d316d/3)

Two tables

1. Customers
2. Orders

How to find all customer's orders between date1 and date 2 even if they have 0 orders?

Here is what I have so far, it works:

```
select c.customer_name
     , c.date_created
     , o.grandtotal
     , o.order_date
  from Customers c
  left 
  join Orders o 
    on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 where exists (select o1.* from Orders o1) 
   and c.customer_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
 group 
    by c.customer_name
```

I need to order by date like so:

```
select c.customer_name, c.date_created, o.grandtotal, o.order_date
from Customers c
left join Orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
where exists (select o1.* from Orders o1) 
and o.order_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-18'
and c.customer_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by c.customer_name
```

Comment: That works without a date range...

Comment: You updated your question, so I deleted my answer. And now your question is not making any sense?

Comment: What doesn't make sense...? I need to query customers table left joined to orders table, I need to see all the results even the customers with zero orders.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How to find all customer's `orders` between date1 and date 2 `even if they have 0 orders`? What are you trying to find? List of all customers + their orders in a specific time period?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (including the customers with 0 orders).

Comment: That's tricky, you cannot put the "o.order_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-18' " where you have it. That won't filter the results correctly.

Comment: None of these queries make much sense. In any other RDBMS, they wouldn't be allowed

Comment: Please see the sql fiddle -- you can see from it that the customer "Price Chopper" has 0 orders and it correctly shows "Null" in the order_date column.
I need that exact query but also need to be able to filter between two dates. Like my second example query shows.

Comment: So what you want is a list of _all_ (or _selected_) users with their orders that fall within a date range, and list those users even if they have no orders in that range...  where a more straightforward query would omit users that have no orders, you want them listed anyway. (1) Pick some customers. (2) Pick a date range. (3a) List all of those customers - no matter what. (3b) list their orders if they have any.

Comment: @StephenP yes - exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. If you want to see all the specific customers and their orders.

```
SELECT
    c.customer_name
    , c.date_created
    , o.grandtotal
    , o.order_date
FROM
    Customers c
    LEFT JOIN Orders o
        ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
            AND o.order_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-18'
WHERE
    c.customer_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it is returning customer's outside of the IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Ah, you want to pass it a list of specific customer_id's as well? sec. @Goldbug updated

Comment: Yes - that did it. Tu!

Answer (score -1):

With the super limited information you provided, I'm pretty sure you're trying to do a LEFT JOIN. Take a look at http://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join for an example that sounds a lot like what you're describing.

Comment: Wow. A down vote for this. So, hoping that it's not you that downvoted this, Goldbug. At the point I answered your question, you had only given this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e358aa5f-62a9-4ea1-a3e2-54c6d4fd0e61/view-source